# Getting response with data even without internet connection

Tags: ios, swift, connection, response, urlsession

Im testing my application behavior when there is no internet connection. Im excepting to get error when user is offline.

I execute this code and getting "data Optional(53161 bytes)" output in console when internet connection disabled.

```
func getCountries(request: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {

    guard let url = url else { print("url is not valid")
        return
    }

    session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            request(nil, error)
            return
        }

        print("data \(data)")
        request(data, nil)

    }.resume()
}
```

So why am I getting response without connection?

Thanks!

Comment: Cache? Print data stringified, might be some cache response...

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or the simulator?

Comment: I use a simulator with turned off wifi on mac

Comment: Everything works on real device. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
func getCountries(request: @escaping (Result<Data,Error>) -> Void) {

    guard let url = URL(string: "yourURL") else {
        print("url is not valid")
        return
    }

    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            request(.failure(error!))
            return
        }
        request(.success(data!))

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And to call the function, do it like this:

```
getCountries() { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    case .success(let success):
        print(success)
    }
}
```